# Error when using list comprehension to add dict to dataframe object

Tags: python, json, pandas, list-comprehension

Having trouble adding dict objects to dataframe when using dict comprehension.

I have some code that I keep getting TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable on, if I run the same code with print it works

The dataframe I have looks like this:

```
organisasjonsnummer institusjonellSektorkode
981260546           {'kode': '2100', 'beskrivelse': 'Private aksje'}
913062159           {'kode': '2100', 'beskrivelse': 'Private aksje'}
975931366           {'kode': '2100', 'beskrivelse': 'Private aksje'}
```

I Would like it to look like this:

```
organisasjonsnummer kode          beskrivelse
981260546           2100        'Private aksje'
913062159           2100        'Private aksje'
975931366           2100        'Private aksje'
```

So I tried to append to the dataframe like this, but I can't get it to work...

```
Dataframe_test['kode'] = [x.get('kode') for x in Dataframe_test['institusjonellSektorkode']]
```

```
# This doesn't work
sample = [x['kode'] for x in SAMPLE_TEST['institusjonellSektorkode']]

# this works
sample = [print(x['kode']) for x in SAMPLE_TEST['institusjonellSektorkode']]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think data are not dicts, but strings in column `institusjonellSektorkode`, so need converting them before by `ast.literal_eval` in list comprehension, create new `DataFrame` and join to original. Function [`pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) is for extracting column:

```
import ast

df1 = pd.DataFrame([ast.literal_eval(x) for x in df.pop('institusjonellSektorkode')])
print (df1)
     beskrivelse  kode
0  Private aksje  2100
1  Private aksje  2100
2  Private aksje  2100

df = df.join(df1)
print (df)
   organisasjonsnummer    beskrivelse  kode
0            981260546  Private aksje  2100
1            913062159  Private aksje  2100
2            975931366  Private aksje  2100
```

Comment: Not shure if I'm misinterpeting what you're doing, but when I try I get: ``` ValueError: malformed node or string: {'kode': '2500', 'beskrivelse': 'Private produsentorienterte organisasjoner uten profittformål'} ```

Answer (score 0):

Oh my.... I found out what went wrong.... I had an error in my dataset. This is the way I corrected it.... lesson learned... Check/wash dataset better next time..

```
import numpy as np

# Simple function to that returns a NaN if it is not fed a dict as an input.
def get_value(dict, string_to_get):
    '''
    takes input of dict, and tries to return the value of the string, if it fails
    it will return null value
    '''
    try:
        get_string = dict.get(string_to_get)
        return get_string
    except:
        return np.nan

Dataframe_test['kode'] = [get_value(x,'kode') for x in Dataframe_test['institusjonellSektorkode']]
```